# Trying to detect products from text while using a dictionary

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I have a list of products names and a collection of text generated from random users. I  am trying to detect products mentioned in the text while talking into account spelling variation. For example the text

Text = i am interested in galxy s8

Mentions the product samsung galaxy s8

But note the difference in spellings.

I've implemented the following approaches:
1- max tokenized products names and users text (i split words by punctuation and digits so s8 will be tokenized into 's' and '8'. Then i did a check on each token in user's text to see if it is in my vocabulary with damerau levenshtein distance <= 1 to allow for variation in spelling. Once i have detected a sequence of tokens that do exist in the vocabulary i do a search for the product that matches the query while checking the damerau levenshtein distance on each token. This gave poor results. Mainly because the sequence of tokens that exist in the vocabulary do not necessarily represent a product. For example since text is max tokenized numbers can be found in the vocabulary and as such dates are detected as products.

2- i constructed bigram and trigram indicies from the list of products and converted each user text into a query.. but also results weren't so great given the spelling variation

3- i manually labeled 270 sentences and trained a named entity recognizer with labels ('O' and 'Product'). I split the data into 80% training and 20% test. Note that I didn't use the list of products as part of the features. Results were okay.. not great tho

None of the above results achieved a reliable performance. I tried regular expressions but since there are so many different combinations to consider it became too complicated.. Are there better ways to tackle this problem? I suppose ner could give better results if i train more data but suppose there isn't enough training data, what do u think a better solution would be?

If i come up with a better alternative to the ones I've already mentioned, I'll add it to this post. In the meantime I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting your problem into two parts.

1) Conduct a spelling check using a dictionary of known product names (this is not a NLP task and there should be guides on how to impelement spell check).

2) Once you have done pre-processing (spell checking), use your NER algorithm

It should improve your accuracy.

Comment: Stanford CoreNLP has regexNER for situations where you have a list of entities to match on